# Using a here-doc for `sed` and a file

Tags: bash, sed, here-document

I want to use a here-doc for sed commands and provide the file to be read and the output file.

I've looked at [Here-Documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) from Advanced  Bash Scripting guide but it does not mention anything about regular arguments in using a here-doc. Is it even possible?

I'd like to achieve something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT=/tmp/outfile.txt
IN=/my_in_file.txt

sed $IN << SED_SCRIPT
    s/a/1/g
    s/test/full/g

SED_SCRIPT 
> $OUT;
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can tell GNU sed to read the script from standard input with `-f -`, `-f` meaning to read the script from a file, and `-` meaning standard input as is common with a lot of commands.

```
sed -f - "$IN" > "$OUT" << SED_SCRIPT
    s/a/1/g
    s/test/full/g
SED_SCRIPT
```

POSIX sed also supports `-f`, but the use of `-` for standard input is not documented. In this case, you could use `/dev/stdin` on Linux systems (and I seem to recall Solaris has this too, but I cannot confirm that right now)

Using `<<-SED_SCRIPT` (with the '-' prefix) will allow the closing `SED_SCRIPT` tag to be indented.

Comment: Thank you, what you said worked, how ever I'd like to point out that the closing token cannot be indented, otherwise it causes an error in bash, I assume this is because it also includes the white-space in the closing one.

Comment: Note that Apple OS X sed does not support reading a script from standard input. (At least not in that manner or any other documented manner.)

Comment: @danorton: I have added a [solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170200/19702) which does not require support of `-f -` in `sed` but it requires process substitution: `<( command )`.

Comment: Note: Redirection operator `<<-` in _Bash Ref. Manual_ : "[_all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)". If the (closing) delimiter is intended with spaces rather than tabs: `bash: warning: here-document at line 21 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'SED_SCRIPT')\bash: bash-script.sh: line 90: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. (Git Bash v2.34.1; GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)). Indentation of the `sed` commands works with tabs _and_ spaces.

Answer (score 7):

In case `sed` does not support reading of a script from `stdin` (using `-f -`), you can use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) (available in `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`):

```
sed "$IN" > "$OUT" -f <( cat << SED_SCRIPT
    s/a/1/g
    s/test/full/g
SED_SCRIPT)
```

The closing parenthesis `)` must follow the end delimiter (`SEC_SCRIPT`) immediately or after a newline. In the case of process substitution you can also use `echo` instead of a here document:

```
sed "$IN" > "$OUT" -f <( echo \
"    s/a/1/g
    s/test/full/g" )
```

Comment: On Mac OS X, it didn't like the input file (`"$IN"` or even `testfile.txt`) immediately following the sed command itself — it wanted a `-e script` or `-f file`. Re-arranging @pabouk 's answer worked for me: `sed -f <( cat << ETC ... ETC) "$IN" > "$OUT"`

Comment: On Max OSX with bash 4.2.45 and standard BSD sed, the *closing parentheses* had to be on a new line below the closing `SED_SCRIPT`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use multiple expressions with `-e` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT=/tmp/outfile.txt
IN=/my_in_file.txt

sed 
  -e "s/a/1/g" \
  -e "s/test/full/g" \
  $IN > $OUT
```

I find that slightly more readable for smaller inline sed scripts.
BTW you could also use the in-place editing of sed:

```
sed -i.org
  -e "s/a/1/g" \
  -e "s/test/full/g" \
  $IN
```

This would save the original file under `${IN}.org` and apply the changes to the input file.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers on this page.  I was looking to be as 'clean'  as I could and came up with this version standing on the shoulders of the suggestions above.  Comments ofr improvment or fixes are always welcome.

Sampe solution:

```
function sed_script()
{
    cat << SED_SCRIPT
  s/a/1/g;
  s/test/full/g;
SED_SCRIPT
}
```

Use as follows:

```
cat "$IN" | sed -f <(sed_script) > "$OUT"
```

Worked on my use case, which had a lot of messy sed commands to run.

Comment: It makes sense to create a function that outputs a `sed` script _if you need to use this `sed` script in many different places_. However, it would probably never be useful to use it without invoking `sed`. It would therefore make more sense to also include the `sed` call in the function, so that you get `sed_script "$IN" >"$OUT"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda ... Good point; although the thrus of making a function is primarily for  maintainability and readability.   Even when ''developing' script, one  still needs to be able to quickly (human-)parse the intention and grok how it ought to apply/work-out.  _imho_

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a nicer approach:

```
OUT=/dev/stdout

IN=my_in_file.txt
sed -s 's/in/out/' < $IN > $OUT
  -or-
sed -s 's/in/out/' > $OUT < $IN

IN=my_in_text
sed -s 's/in/out/' <<< $IN > $OUT
  -or-
sed -s 's/in/out/' > $OUT <<< $IN
```

:)

Comment: Interesting, but besides the point. The OP wants to pass sed commands via stdin.

Comment: This approach allows both methods, why the downvote?

Comment: Repeat: "pass sed commands via stdin". You answer doesn't do that by any method.